# Getting maxlength from array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the longest description from `$productDetail` array, but it returns empty array elements:

```
$desc = array_map(function($a) { 
            return (!!$desc && strlen($desc) < strlen($a["desc"])) ? 
                $a["desc"] : $desc;
        }, $productDetail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$desc = array_reduce(array_map(function($a) { return $a["desc"]; }, $productDetail), 
            function ($a, $b) { return strlen($a) > strlen($b) ? $a : $b; }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$desc` inside of your assignment of `$desc` before it's completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $cars);
$maxLength = max($lengths);
$index = array_search($maxLength, $lengths);
echo $cars[$index];
```